# Migrate Intentservices to Workmanager

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

We are currently using around 10 android Intent service for our background task. We have planned to migrate to Work manager workers for all of them.

Library is still in alpha stage. Is it safe to migrate now?

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes